# How to disable output to serial (GPIO) during boot

Tags: gpio, boot, pi-3b+, serial, dc-motor

I'm trying to drive a motor control over the Raspberry Pi's GPIO serial pins (GPIO 14 and 15)

I've disabled the serial console, however, during bootup of the Raspberry PI, it still sends data over the serial pins. This sends seemingly random commands to the motor controller. Which is of course potentially dangerous and not what I want to happen.

My system:

- Raspberry Pi 3 B+
- Serial connection with the motor controller over GPIO 14 (it's one way, so GPIO 15 is not connected)
- Ubuntu MATE 18.04.4 LTS

What I have already tried:

- Use raspi-config to disable serial console (3 Interface Options > P5 1-wire > no (login shell) > yes (serial port) => this did not seem to work at all.
- in /boot/firmware/nobtcmd.txt I have removed the "console" parameter => this correctly disabled the login shell

What is working:

- When the Pi is booted, I can connect to the motor driver and send it commands. This works correctly

What is not working:

- During boot I have to disconnect the serial connection to the motor driver, because data is transmitted over the connection

My question:

- How can I completely disable all data written to the serial interface during boot?

Comment: What data is being sent?  What motor?  What motor controller?

Comment: The driver does not show what data it receives. Is there an easy way to figure that out? Can I connect another Raspberry Pi to read this?

Comment: Use Raspberry Pi OS. Ubuntu uses Canonical kernel and firmware.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters, but it's the Sabertooth 2X5 in simplified serial mode with two DC motors connected. The driver is receiving data, when no data is expected over the serial connection.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu MATE because that's what ROS prefers. I will set up Raspberry Pi OS on a separate card to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: After a quick test, it turns out @Milliways suggestion fixed this. The latest Raspberry Pi OS does not transmit anything over the serial connection if the serial shell is disabled. I'm going to leave this question open, because I would prefer a solution using Ubuntu (I have a feeling it might take quite some work to get ROS running on Rasp Pi OS, but still need to test this)

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem as described above when using a raspberry pi 4 with a RS485 hat to talk to a controller for a stepper motor. During each boot or shutdown process some stuff was sent over the serial link causing the controller to go into an alarm state.
None of the tips above solved the issue (using latest Raspberry Pi OS, login shell - no, serial port - yes, removing all mentions of the serial interface from /boot/cmdline.txt).

Finally I found out that the GPIO14 pin was in an undefined state during boot / after shutdown. So adding an external 10 kOhm pull-up resistor between 3.3V and GPIO14 fixed the issue.